# How to remove the gap from the chart in TWS?

Tags: interactive-brokers

TWS shoes a gap for the time which the market is offline. How to remove the gap?

Is there any way to see the pre-market and aftermarket time but hide them for the tickers which are not exchanged out of RTH?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you open the charting menu, down at the bottom there is a choice that says something like "Show Extended Hours".  If you uncheck it, the after hours gap should disappear.

Comment: Thanks, I still cannot find such an option. There are many menus, which one do you refer to?

Comment: Open a chart and go to its menu.  At the bottom of the page it says "Chart Time Options".  Make sure that the box that says "Show Data Outside of Regular Hours" is unchecked.  If you don't see these choices then we're probably on different versions. Plan B?  Call tech support.